# “the family of paupers whom he had just come to trouble with his presence” – which verb or preposition is connected with “whom”?

Tags: relative-clauses

> But there was no talk about the other baby, Tom Canty, lapped in his
> poor rags, except among the family of paupers **whom** he had just
> come to trouble with his presence.

From "the Prince and the Pauper".

Which verb or preposition in "he had just come to trouble with his presence" is connected with "whom"?

Comment: ***whom*** is "connected" to ***the family of paupers*** (of which semantically, it's just a pointless repetition). It could be replaced by ***that*** or ***which***, or simply discarded completely without affecting anything.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I mean the relative clause. "he had just somebody come to trouble with his presence"? "he had just come to trouble with somebody his presence"? ”he had just come to trouble somebody with his presence“?

Comment: *he had just come to trouble **the family of paupers** with his presence*. But if you're trying to learn "current" English, convoluted phrasing in antiquated literary texts by the likes of Twain, Dickens, Bronte, etc. aren't really much use. They're certainly not suitable for the *early* stages of learning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought it was an easy book.

Comment: No. Most C19 literary texts weren't particularly "easy" even for the average native Anglophone back when they were written. More recent texts by Hemmingway or Orwell would be much easier *and* more effective. And check out writers like Isaac Asimov and Robert Heinlein, if you like sci-fi.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What about "Oliver Twister" by Dickens?

Comment: Or JK Rowling if you don't mind text primarily aimed at children! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You mean Harry Potter?

Comment: It's the same writer regardless of the specific book (I don't suppose she changes her basic style much).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I summarise what has in fact been answered by @FumbleFingers.

*whom* refers to *the family of paupers*.  It is also the object of the relative clause

> whom he had just come to trouble with his presence

The relative clause means

> he had just come to trouble *the family of paupers* with his presence

To answer your question, the infinitive *to trouble* is that verb.  We say *whom* is the object of the infinitive.